# SSRS Toggle Visibility not functioning properly

Tags: reporting-services

I have an 2016 SSRS report that hides and shows rows based on toggles. The report was recently updated to 2016 from 2005 and the toggles broke on the 2016 server. However, when using Visual Studio 2017 preview mode, the report works as expected. Thus making it hard to determine where the error is. Any ideas? The schema in the XML is set to 2016.

Comment: What is the target version in the project properties?

Comment: SQL Server 2016 or later